# How to create topic in Kafka with Python-kafka admin client?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

is there any Python kafka admin client avilable to create topic/delete topic from python program ? I found some python apis but none of them have Admin api available ?

Does confluent have python admin api ?

Answer (score 8):

```
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient, NewTopic
admin_client = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092", client_id='test')

topic_list = []
topic_list.append(NewTopic(name="example_topic", num_partitions=1, replication_factor=1))
admin_client.create_topics(new_topics=topic_list, validate_only=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this:

> https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python

It worked for me, at least, at the topic creation, I specify one or multiple topics and it creates them in my kafka broker.

See my own answer:

> [Could I create a topic in Kafka via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890614/could-i-create-a-topic-in-kafka-via-api?noredirect=1#comment111215362_62890614)

I asked practically the same as you.

Example of use:

```
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, NewTopic

topic = sys.argv[1]

topics = ["newTopicExample","newTopicExample2"]

# Create topic in our Kafka, using kafka-python library.
a = AdminClient({'bootstrap.servers': 'myKafkaBrokerURL'})

new_topics = [NewTopic(topic, num_partitions=3, replication_factor=1) for topic in topics]

# Call create_topics to asynchronously create topics. A dict
# of <topic,future> is returned.
fs = a.create_topics(new_topics)

# Wait for each operation to finish.
for topic, f in fs.items():
    try:
        f.result()  # The result itself is None
        print("Topic {} created".format(topic))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to create topic {}: {}".format(topic, e))
```

Answer (score -3):

The [Confluent Python Kafka Client](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) does indeed have admin support.

Check out this [example](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/adminapi.py) to learn how to use it.