# Could I create a topic in Kafka via API? Using any python library

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-rest

I'm trying to find information about the topic creation in Kafka via API, because I need to automate some tasks, It would be great if someone knows if it's possible, I was reading here:

> https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#crest-api-v3

But it didn't work for me. If I try to do

```
GET in /v3/clusters/ --> returns code 404
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create a topic with Kafka Rest Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764243/is-it-possible-to-create-a-topic-with-kafka-rest-proxy)

Comment: More or less... I haven't got Kafka Rest Proxy installed and configured, so to create kafka topics from API Rest I'm using confluent-kafka library from here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html

Comment: okay, then you might think to rephrase your question. You are not mentioning something about Python (only the tag) and put a link to the REST API. This was very misleading to me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question.

I post here what I found, that rest endpoint is useful only in case you have configured kafka rest proxy, if not, try to use any external library.

If found this one:

> https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html

"Kafka Admin client: create, view, alter, delete topics and resources."